# Adding non-existing combination

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make a table with all available products for every customer. However, I only have a table with the combination of product and customer if it was bought. I want to make a new table that also included the product that were not bought by the customer. The current table looks as follows:

[image: initial table]

The table I want to end up with is:

[image: final table]

Could anyone help me how to do this in pandas?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you finished before posting, especially [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `pd.MultiIndex` and `reindex`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Product':list('ABCDEF'),
                   'Customer':[1,1,2,3,3,3],
                   'Amount':[4,5,3,1,1,2]})

indx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['Product'].unique(), 
                                   df['Customer'].unique()], 
                                  names=['Product','Customer'])

df.set_index(['Product','Customer'])\
  .reindex(indx, fill_value=0)\
  .reset_index()\
  .sort_values(['Customer','Product'])
```

Output:

```
   Product  Customer  Amount
0        A         1       4
3        B         1       5
6        C         1       0
9        D         1       0
12       E         1       0
15       F         1       0
1        A         2       0
4        B         2       0
7        C         2       3
10       D         2       0
13       E         2       0
16       F         2       0
2        A         3       0
5        B         3       0
8        C         3       0
11       D         3       1
14       E         3       1
17       F         3       2
```

Comment: To get the desired output in the OP, you would also want to add `df.sort_values(['Customer','Product'])`

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a pivot to do what you want in one line. Note that the output format is different -- it's a pandas.DataFrame.pivot rather than a standard pandas data frame. But if you're not especially fussed about that (depends on how you intend to use the final table), the following code does the job.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Product':['A','B','C','D','E','F'],
                   'Customer':[1,1,2,3,3,3],
                   'Amount':[4,5,3,1,1,2]})
pivot_df = df.pivot(index='Product', 
                    columns='Customer',          
                    values='Amount').fillna(0).astype('int')

Output:

Customer  1  2  3
Product          
A         4  0  0
B         5  0  0
C         0  3  0
D         0  0  1
E         0  0  1
F         0  0  2
```

df.pivot creates NaN values when there are no corresponding entries in the original df (it creates a NaN value for Product A and Customer 2, for instance). NaNs are float values, so all the 'Amounts' in the pivot are implicitly converted into floats. This is why I use fillna(0) to convert the NaN values into 0s, and then finally change the dtype back to int.